# What is the dose-dependence of cigarette smoking and skin damage?

Tags: dermatology, smoking

I am aware that the number of cigarettes smoked does not scale linearly with risk to cardiovascular and lung health, with even occasional smoking significantly increasing risk (Schane et al., 2010. PMCID [2865193](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2865193)). I was wondering if the same applied to skin damage and acceleration of skin ageing, or whether the relationship in that case would be more linear. If this question has not specifically been studied, speculation of scaling based on the aetiology of skin damage would be welcome.

Comment: There are few absolutes in medicine; this is also not one of them. You should search specifically for the effects of smoking on skin appearance/aging (your link is too general to smoking and health), and quote/link to that with any question you have about what you've read.